# How to know which test to chose when proving the convergence of a serie?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove the convergence of this serie :

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}}$$

I tought the easiest would be to use the ratio test, however I can't figure out how to solve. Which let me believe that I've chosen the wrong test.

I'm currently studying series and I keep facing the same issue :

How to know which test I should chose when proving the convergence of a serie ? Maybe there is a pattern to apply, or it simply comes with practice ?

Comment: Hint: The $n$-th term is $\ge \frac{1}{2n}$.  As to choosing method, for series with positive terms the usual issue is whether the terms approach $0$ "fast enough."

Comment: Use squeezing: $n^2<n^2+n\le2n^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: It behaves as
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}
$$
(ratio test), hence...

And in general there is no rule, how to verify the convergence of a series. Practice, practice, practice...

Answer (score 2):

Since, $\sqrt{n^2}=n$, it makes sense to use the limit comparison test with $1/n$.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{1/\sqrt{n^2+n}\over1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over\sqrt{n^2+n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over\sqrt{1+1/n}}=1.$$

Now, since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$ diverges, the given series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

There is pattern and also practice which will make you decide which test to apply .

To know about which test to apply to which problems see video given in link below .They are by Adrisn Banner of Princeton Uiniversity  .Will certainly be helpful to you

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6Yo1hYf9eM

Answer (score 1):

All you need to know is the general behaviour of some important functions:
$$x!,e^x,x^n,\ln x$$
Generally the function which grows faster than the others is $x!$ then is $e^x$ , $x^n$ and last  is the logarithm $\ln x$ which grows too slow.
The rule is the following:
If you add,subtract,multiply or divide any combination of those two functions the faster will prevail.
For example if you want to test the convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{x^2 +\ln x}$ you know that the series behaves actually like $\sum \frac{1}{x^2}$ (which converges).
The series $\sum \frac{1}{x+e^x}$ behaves like $\sum \frac{1}{e^x}$.
But if you want **to prove** that it converges you have to use the ratio test.
Some hint to show you how to have an idea for the behaviour of the series.